# Sending email and constructing Mimes in php

Tags: php, email

I am sending an email with php. Those are my headers.

```
$headers = array (
'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
'From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Return-Path' => 'info@example.com',
'Content-Type'=>  'multipart/alternative',
'boundary'=>$boundary,  
'Subject' => $subject);

 $random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
```

That is my html/textbody:

```
    $bodyHTML = "
 --PHP-alt-$random_hash 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
http://example.com/app_dl.php?app_id=$_GET[app_id] to download your $app_name app \n\r\n\r
Want to get tons more hot apps for free! anywhere anytime? Download our app on http://example.com' \n\r\n\r
example.com team
--PHP-alt-$random_hash 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
<p><a href='http://example.com/app_dl.php?app_id=$_GET[app_id]'>Click Here</a> to download your $app_name app</p>
<p>Want to get tons more hot apps for free! anywhere anytime? Download our app on <a href='http://example.com'>example.com</a></p>
<br/>
<p>example.com team</p> 
--PHP-alt-$random_hash--";
```

I have been stuck on that problem for a long time, now.. What am I missing

Comment: What *are* you missing? What is the problem you have with this code?

Comment: that the body is not being sent properly

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove leading spaces and add linebreaks:

```
    $boundary = "PHP_alt_$random_hash";
    $bodyHTML = "--$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

http://example.com/app_dl.php?app_id=$_GET[app_id] to download your $app_name app \n\r\n\r
Want to get tons more hot apps for free! anywhere anytime? Download our app on http://example.com' \n\r\n\r
example.com team

--$boundary 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p><a href='http://example.com/app_dl.php?app_id=$_GET[app_id]'>Click Here</a> to download your $app_name app</p>
<p>Want to get tons more hot apps for free! anywhere anytime? Download our app on <a href='http://example.com'>example.com</a></p>
<br/>
<p>example.com team</p>

--$boundary--";
```

Comment: boundary is :  $boundary="PHP-alt-".$random_hash;

Comment: try to replace "-" symbol with "_" in boundary

Comment: $boundary="PHP_alt_".$random_hash  ... like that

Comment: ok, and your message should be:
--{$boundary}
headers\n\n
body\n\n
--{$boundary}
header\n
header\n\n
body\n\n
--{$boundary}--

Comment: How can I change the from to a text that will appear when the user receives the message, instead of the email?

Comment: it's based on your application, basic solution: replace mail() with var_dump() of parameters. and for body you can str_replace("\n", "\\n\n") to show line breaks

Comment: I cant understand what you mean.. could u post or update your answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11080/discussion-between-dmitry-makovetskiyd-and-electronick)